# Prospect mail not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: email

I've tried in install Prospect mail in Ubuntu 22.04
It is listed in the Activities menu.

When I try to launch it, nothing appears to work.

Is there a help file I can use to try to get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

happens to me also some days ago on Kubuntu 22.04. Simply substitute the executable path with "/snap/bin/prospect-mail %U". Or try to launch it from a terminal(as normal user, not root).

Greetings

Comment: Hi, I've tried to start prospect from the terminal, nothing appears to happen. where would I find the executable path? Do you know where I could find a list of dependencies, I googled the hell out of it and only seem to find info on installing prospect mail, rather than fault finding the problem. Cheers

Comment: For dependencies use ldd path to executable. i.e. ldd /snap/bin/prospect-mail. I stopped using prospect-mail because with e-mails that have a long history, it's very slow and jerks to a halt. I now use outlook via the web, which is more streamlined and faster than prospect-mail.
Too bad because I like prospect-mail, but it's to be optimized

Comment: Thank you for your help. based on the info you gave me I was able to alter the .desktop file and set the path to /snap/prospect-mail/current/prospect-mail %U. It launches fine now, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Please try the newer version 0.5.0 !
https://github.com/julian-alarcon/prospect-mail/releases/tag/v0.5.0